# ¿Cómo descomprimir el alfabeto de literales/longitudes en el método de compresión DEFLATE?

Tags: imagen, algoritmos

he estado trabajando en un lector para los archivos **PNG**. He entendido que trabaja en trozos por así decirlo, por el momento he entendido gran parte de la información que posee ese tipo de archivo, mas sin embargo he hallado a tener un problema a la hora de obtener la tabla de longitudes, ésto debido principalmente a que no entiendo del todo cómo es que se genera dichos códigos.

He seguido el tutorial de http://www.dreamcoder.org/2008/07/analisis-formato-png.html en el cual posee un ejemplo que he seguido pero como he resaltado anteriormente me he quedado atorado en la decodificación de la tabla de longitudes, éstos son los datos en bits que muestran que son parte del deflate:

> 01001101 10001010 10111001 00001101 00000000 00110000 00001100 10000100 00111000 11001001 11011111 11111110 00001011 11011011 01010111 10100100 00001000 00010101 01001000 11000000 10000111 00110010 01001011 01100010 01101101 01101100 11001100 10010100 11001101 00100101 00010100 11011101 11110011 00011110 01110100

Éstos son los datos obtenidos:

> HLIT = 266 HDIST = 11 HCEN = 16

Según los datos obtenido he sacado los bytes se ha obtenido los siguientes datos:

> el valor de los bits: {3, 0, 2, 4, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   4, 3, 3}
>
> Número de elementos para cada longitud de código: {0, 0, 1, 5, 2}
>
> Menor valor para cada longitud de código:{0, 0, 0, 2, 14}

Por lo que el resultado final de la disposición sería:

> {010, -, 00, 1110, 011, 100, -, -, -, -, -, -, -, -, -, -, 1111, 101,
>   110}

Por lo que el código de longitudes debe de quedar así (la cual es la que no logro entender):

> 00 (2:literal), 1110 (3), 010 (0), 010 (0), 011 (4)
>
> 1111 : 16 - leemos 2 bits extra: 01 = 1 + 3 = 4 (4 4"s)
>
> 110 : 18 - leemos 7 bits extra: 1111111 = 127 + 11 = 138 (138 veces
>   0),
>
> 110 : 18 - 1100001 = 97 + 11 = 108 (108 veces 0)
>
> 011 (4), 011 (4), 1110 (3)
>
> 101 : 17 - leemos 3 bits extra: 000 = 0 + 3 = 3 (3 veces 0),
>
> 100 (5)
>
> 101 : 17 - leemos 3 bits extra: 000 = 0 + 3 = 3 (3 veces 0),
>
> 100 (5)

y su representación así:

{2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 3, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5}